# Mounting a virtual environment via SSHFS on local machine using it's Python3 file not working

Tags: python, django, ssh, virtualenv, sshfs

So I have mounted a part of a development server which hold a virtual environment that is used for development testing. The reason for this is to get access to the installed packages such as Django-rest-framework and Django itself and not having it set up locally (to be sure to use the same version as the development server has). I know that it's perhaps better to use Docker for this, but that's not the case right now.

The way I've done it is installing SSHFS via an external brew (as it's no longer supported in the brew core) - via this link https://github.com/gromgit/homebrew-fuse

After that I've run this command in the terminal to via SSH mount the specific part of the development server that holds the virtual enviornment:

```
sshfs -o ssh_command='ssh -i /Users/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa' myusername@servername:/home/myusername/projectname/env/bin ~/mnt/projectname
```

It works fine and I have it mounted on my local disk in mnt/projectname.

Now I go into VSCode and go into the folder and select the file called "python3" as my interpreter (which I should, right?). However, this file is just an alias, being 16 bytes in size. I suspect something is wrong here, but I'm not sure on how to fix it. Can someone maybe take a look and give some input? I'll attach a screenshot of the mounted directory.

[Screenshot of virtualenv directory mounted on local machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhT5L.png)

Comment: Virtual environments are not portable. You shouldn't copy them or mount them to a different host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem was using the VSCode extension Remote - SSH and run VSCode directly in the remote location, and from there being able to access the virtual environment.